# how to select all not NULL values in from every column... Need LINQ or ADO query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

Please answer this question... i m trying to make single table instead of having multiple tables

Table structure like

```
ID    COL1       COL2      COL3   ...  ...
1     SHIRT      NULL      NULL
2     SKIRT      NULL      NULL
3     TROUSER    NULL      NULL
4     NULL       WINTER    NULL
5     NULL       SUMMER    NULL
6     NULL       AUTUMN    NULL
7     NULL       NULL      NIGHT
8     NULL       NULL      EVENING
9     NULL       NULL      NULL
.     ..         ..        ..
```

Comment: Please add expected result....

Comment: can you please post the out put ?? here you showing mutliple columns but not showing any multiple tables

Comment: Instead i make 3 tables, i made one table with 3 columns... now i want 1 select statement that gives me all not null values

Comment: expected result would be like

ID    COL1           COL2            COL3   ...  ...
1     SHIRT           WINTER        NIGHT
2     SKIRT           SUMMER      EVENING
3     TROUSER    AUTUMN       NULL

.

Comment: What is the logic to match SHIRT WINTER and NIGHT as one row?

Comment: select col1,col2 from table where col1 is not null and col2 is not null

I need this type selection but it is returning no rows...

Comment: "returning no rows", maybe you should show what you do. At SO people are specifically allergic to please-give-me-the-code style of questions. Showing some effort is highly appreciated.

Comment: @dipz as per provided we can achieve the result using CTE

Answer (score 0):

**we can achieve this by using row_number ,order by and Common table Expression**

```
declare @table table(ID int,Col1 varchar(10),col2 Varchar(10),Col3 Varchar(10))
insert into @table(ID,Col1,col2,col3)values (1,'Shirt',NULL,NULL) ,
(2,'SKIRT',NULL,NULL),(3,'TROUSER',NULL,NULL),(4,NULL,'WINTER',NULL),(5,NULL,'SUMMER',NULL)
,(6,NULL,'AUTUMN ',NULL),(7,NULL,NULL,'NIGHT'),(8,NULL,NULL,'Evening')
;with CTE AS (
select col1,ROW_NUMBER()OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))R from @table
where Col1 is not NULL
), CTE1 AS (
select col2,ROW_NUMBER()OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))R from @table
where Col2 is not NULL
), CTE2 AS (
select col3,ROW_NUMBER()OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))R from @table
where Col3 is not NULL
)
select c.col1,cc.col2,ccc.Col3 from CTE C INNER JOIN cte1  CC
ON c.R = cc.R LEFT JOIN CTE2 CCC ON 
CCC.R = C.R
```